# Strange bitset output after cast from uint64_t to double and back to uint64_t

Tags: c++, casting, bitset

I have the following program:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint64_t big = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    double d_big = static_cast<double>(big);
    uint64_t big_d_big = static_cast<uint64_t>(d_big);

    std::cout << big << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(uint64_t) * 8>(big) << std::endl;

    std::cout << big_d_big << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(uint64_t) * 8>(big_d_big) << std::endl;
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
18446744073709551615
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
73896
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Although I was expecting a loss of information converting to a double and then converting back, how come 'big' and 'big_d_big', which have the same uint64_t type, have identical bitsets but different values? Shouldn't the bitsets also be different given the loss of information? If it helps I am using Clang 17.0.6 x86_64. Also, out of curiosity, where is '73896' specifically coming from in the conversion process?

Comment: A double cannot represent all values of uint64. So it gets rounded. Rounded up. So a conversion down to uint64 becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: So using a long double (with extended precision (80 bits) should not display this behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you try it, and find out.

Comment: @YeovilSound: [Correct](https://godbolt.org/z/GMo74Whej), at least on an implementation where `long double` really is extended precision or more, such that it can exactly represent the number 2^64-1.  (This is not the case for all implementations, not even all x86 implementations.)